# Find and replace value in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, replace

How can I find some value from cell and replace by new value in Excel?

I tryed this but it doesn't works:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb =default(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook);

wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(FileName.ToString());

wb.Worksheets[0].Cells.Replace("find","replace");
```

Comment: What do you mean _it doesn't works_? Any exception or..?

Comment: If that's all your code does, then it should work fine, but you're going to have to be more specific about where it doesn't work and how you know.

Comment: For anyone who finds this later. Worksheets[x] is not 0-based it starts at 1. wb.Sheets.Count; can get you the number of sheets and a for loop can iterate the find-replace through every one of them. Also, you need wb.Save(); and wb.Close(); at the end to actually save the changes and close the document.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) which can be accessed either via codeplex or directly through Nuget in Visual Studio. It gives you the ability to easily upload, edit and create spreadsheets in .NET

Example of uploading a spreadsheet:

```
HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook;

void InitializeWorkbook(string path)
{
    //read the template via FileStream, it is suggested to use FileAccess.Read to prevent file lock.
    //book1.xls is an Excel-2007-generated file, so some new unknown BIFF records are added. 
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    }
}
```

You can then use the IRow and ICell collections of the spreadsheet to locate and edit the data you need before doing an export.

More examples can be found [here](https://npoi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NPOI.Examples/)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is replace

```
wb.Worksheets[0].Cells.Replace("find","replace");
```

with

```
wb.Worksheets[1].Cells.Replace("find","replace");
```

Answer (score 2):

If interested, you can use [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-library/601) for this, like so:

```
SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

// Load your XLS, XLSX, ODS or CSV file.
ExcelFile wb = ExcelFile.Load(FileName.ToString());
ExcelWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

// Replace all "find" occurances with "replace" text.
int row, column;
while(ws.Cells.FindText("find", out row, out column))
    ws.Cells[row, column].ReplaceText("find", "replace");

// Save your XLS, XLSX, ODS or CSV file.
wb.Save(FileName.ToString());
```

Also you can find another [searching in Excel example here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/excel-search/109).